# R for loop with if else on multiple data frames

Tags: r, if-statement

Greetings and thanks in advance for all help
I have many data frame that resemble the ones below

df1

```
   name info
1  john    A
2   jim    B
3   tom    B
4 bill     B
```

dframe

```
  name other
1  sam   pro
2  dad   mo1
3  mom  Bxxx
```

frame3

```
   name otherinfo
1   jus         A
2    do         7
3 r pro         B
4   sir         B
5  real        na
6  pete       yes
```

OLFrame

```
   name information
1  ally          x1
2   mom          B9
3 r pro         s3B
4   tom         Bd0
5 kelly          ot
6  jojo         who
7    na          11
```

I would like to :

1. take each name from the "name" column of dataframe "OLFrame" and look into the "name"column of "df1" to see if the name exists
2. create column vector with named "df1" consisting of "1" if name from "OLFrame" exist in "df1" if not "0"
3. repeat the steps 1 and 2 but using "dframe" and "frame3"
4. create a new data frame called "newOLFrame" consisting of "OLFrame" and and new columns named "df1", "dframe" and "frame3"

The desired result should look like

newOLFrame

```
   name information df1 dframe frame3
1  ally          x1   0      0      0
2   mom          B9   0      1      0
3 r pro         s3B   0      0      1
4   tom         Bd0   1      0      0
5 kelly          ot   0      0      0
6  jojo         who   0      0      0
7    na          11   0      0      0
```

I can do one at a time (below) but I have over a hundred files to look through

```
newOLFrame<-OLFrame
newOLFrame[,"pro1"]<-ifelse(newOLFrame$name %in% df12$name, 1, 0)
```

Please help. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Consider an extended chain merge by first building a list of data frames, iteratively left joined to *OLFrame* then chain merge all together at end with `Reduce`:

```
df_list <- lapply(c("df1", "dframe", "frame3"), function(nm) {      
  df <- get(nm)
  df[[nm]] <- 1

  df <- merge(OLFrame, df[c("name", nm)], by="name", all.x=TRUE) 
  df[[nm]] = ifelse(is.na(df[[nm]]), 0, 1)

  return(df)
})

# MERGE ALL DFs
final_df <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by=c("name", "information")), df_list)
final_df
#    name information df1 dframe frame3
# 1  ally          x1   0      0      0
# 2  jojo         who   0      0      0
# 3 kelly          ot   0      0      0
# 4   mom          B9   0      1      0
# 5    na          11   0      0      0
# 6 r pro         s3B   0      0      1
# 7   tom         Bd0   1      0      0
```

---

Alternatively, consider a `do.call` as `Reduce` can have performance issues for large lists where you order data frame and then subset out only the needed column to column bind all data frame items at end:

```
df_list <- lapply(c("df1", "dframe", "frame3"), function(nm) {

  df <- get(nm)
  df[[nm]] <- 1

  df <- merge(OLFrame, df[c("name", nm)], by="name", all.x=TRUE, sort=FALSE) 
  df[[nm]] = ifelse(is.na(df[[nm]]), 0, 1)

  df <- with(df, df[order(name, information),])        # ORDER DATA FRAME
  small_df <- setNames(as.data.frame(df[[nm]]), nm)    # SUBSET ONE COLUMN

  return(small_df)
})

# ORDER DATA FRAME
OLFrame <- with(OLFrame, OLFrame[order(name, information),])

final_df <- do.call(cbind, c(OLFrame, df_list))
final_df

#    name information df1 dframe frame3
# 1  ally          x1   0      0      0
# 2  jojo         who   0      0      0
# 3 kelly          ot   0      0      0
# 4   mom          B9   0      1      0
# 5    na          11   0      0      0
# 6 r pro         s3B   0      0      1
# 7   tom         Bd0   1      0      0
```

Comment: Thank you. How should the code be tweaked if the "name" column was two columns "firstname" , "lastname"?

Comment: Replace *name* with those two as additional items in *df* column selection and *by* argument.

Comment: I did that and it worked well, thanks. On large files it is slow; can anything be done to make it faster. Its given memory error, other than reducing the amount of files in the environment; can anything else be done?

Comment: Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 91674, 843779, 52800

Comment: The results from the various files are of differing lengths and this hinders the final merge: " final_df <- do.call(cbind, c(OLFrame, df_list))"  it give a message "Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 91674, 843779, 52800" .  Please help

Comment: The merge inside ensures same number of rows being a left join. You might have repeating *name* in actual data unlike posted data which works with `do.call`.

Comment: You are right the issue is that there are repeating names (different people with same names) in the original data and I don't have another identifier. Can anything be done to complete the merge?

Comment: You will have to normalize the names somehow to get distinct before this merging process. Hence, why we use number IDs in data world and not string names!